# Create formula for counting number of strings from another sheet using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a formula to count number of `remarks` string present in a column of another sheet. But the formula is created for current sheet itself.

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(lnRow + 5, 6).Value = "=COUNTIFS(" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(3, 9), Cells(30, 9)).Address(False, False) & ", ""remarks"")"
```

It is creating formula for `Sheet2` column itself, but I want from `Sheet1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not actually putting the sheet name in the formula.

Comment: I have put Worksheets("Sheet1") in the formula. But i don't think its the correct way.

Comment: You are not using the `.Formula`property. `... .Range(Cells(3, 9), Cells(30, 9)) ... ` best to be explicit on the range/cells parent... If Cells index values are fixed, you can use a static string. `... .Range("I3:I30") & ", ...`, and if the name of the sheet is known you can prepend it and use "Sheet1!I3:I30". So the formula would be `Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(lnRow + 5, 6).Formula "=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!I3:I30,""remarks"")"`.

Comment: Cell index are not static. I have to replace them with variable name.

Comment: Change `"=COUNTIFS("` to `"=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!"`.

Comment: This solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually putting the sheet name in the formula:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(3, 9), Cells(30, 9)).Address(False, False)
```

doesn't return the sheet name; it returns `I3:I30`.

Change `"=COUNTIFS("` to `"=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!"` to actually include the sheet name.

It is also preferable to use `.Formula` instead of `.Value` here.